# convert row to column and group by key

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have a table that like below:

foo_table

[image]

What i'm trying to archive is some thing like:

```
[DepartmentName] , [4] , [5] , [6]
```

Below is what i tried:

```
select DepartmentName,
CASE foo_table.keyid WHEN '4' THEN foo_table.Score END AS [4],
CASE foo_table.keyid WHEN '5' THEN foo_table.Score END AS [5],
CASE foo_table.keyid WHEN '6' THEN foo_table.Score END AS [6]
     from foo_table
```

[image]

How to group them by [DepartmentName]?

Comment: By they way, it's sql server 2000, therefore, i can't use PIVOT to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select DepartmentName,
max(CASE foo_table.keyid WHEN '4' THEN foo_table.Score END) AS [4],
max(CASE foo_table.keyid WHEN '5' THEN foo_table.Score END) AS [5],
max(CASE foo_table.keyid WHEN '6' THEN foo_table.Score END) AS [6]
     from foo_table
group by DepartmentName;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `Max` function

```
SELECT DepartmentName,
       MAX(CASE foo_table.keyid WHEN '4' THEN foo_table.Score END) AS [4],
       MAX(CASE foo_table.keyid WHEN '5' THEN foo_table.Score END) AS [5],
       MAX(CASE foo_table.keyid WHEN '6' THEN foo_table.Score END) AS [6]
FROM foo_table
GROUP BY DepartmentName;
```

But i'm suggesting you to use **`PIVOT`** instead of above.

Try Like this

```
SELECT  DepartmentName,keyid,Score
FROM foo_table X
PIVOT
(
 MAX(Score) FOR keyid IN ([4],[5],[6]) 
) P;
```

Comment: Thanks @Kumar, yes, it should be more easier with PIVOT, but my live server is sql server 2000, which doesn't support PIVOT